# Chnaging ggplot colors and increasing the size of the text (inside the plot area)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the `xgboostExplainer` package and I make my plot using the `showWaterfall` function. I would like to make the output of the `showWaterfall` plot a little more custom. I first run the following:

```
library(xgboost)
library(xgboostExplainer)
data(agaricus.train, package='xgboost')
data(agaricus.test, package='xgboost')
train <- agaricus.train
test <- agaricus.test

xgb.train.data <- xgb.DMatrix(train$data, label = train$label)
xgb.test.data <- xgb.DMatrix(test$data, label = test$label)
param <- list(objective = "binary:logistic")
xgb.model <- xgboost(param =param,  data = xgb.train.data, nrounds = 10)
explained <- buildExplainer(xgb.model, xgb.train.data, type="binary", base_score = 0.5)
pred.breakdown = explainPredictions(xgb.model,
                                    explained,
                                    xgb.test.data)

showWaterfall(xgb.model,
              explained,
              xgb.test.data, test$data,  2, type = "binary")
```

Next I go to the function of the `showWaterfall` from [here](https://github.com/AppliedDataSciencePartners/xgboostExplainer/blob/master/R/showWaterfall.R) and make some modifications to the `ggplot` part of the code.

```
showWaterfall2 = function(xgb.model, explainer, DMatrix, data.matrix, idx, type = "binary", threshold = 0.0001, limits = c(NA, NA)){


  breakdown = explainPredictions(xgb.model, explainer, slice(DMatrix,as.integer(idx)))

  weight = rowSums(breakdown)
  if (type == 'regression'){
    pred = weight
  }else{
    pred = 1/(1+exp(-weight))
  }


  breakdown_summary = as.matrix(breakdown)[1,]

  data_for_label = data.matrix[idx,]

  i = order(abs(breakdown_summary),decreasing=TRUE)

  breakdown_summary = breakdown_summary[i]
  data_for_label = data_for_label[i]

  intercept = breakdown_summary[names(breakdown_summary)=='intercept']
  data_for_label = data_for_label[names(breakdown_summary)!='intercept']
  breakdown_summary = breakdown_summary[names(breakdown_summary)!='intercept']

  i_other =which(abs(breakdown_summary)<threshold)
  other_impact = 0

  if (length(i_other > 0)){
    other_impact = sum(breakdown_summary[i_other])
    names(other_impact) = 'other'
    breakdown_summary = breakdown_summary[-i_other]
    data_for_label = data_for_label[-i_other]
  }

  if (abs(other_impact) > 0){
    breakdown_summary = c(intercept, breakdown_summary, other_impact)
    data_for_label = c("", data_for_label,"")
    labels = paste0(names(breakdown_summary)," = ", data_for_label)
    labels[1] = 'intercept'
    labels[length(labels)] = 'other'
  }else{
    breakdown_summary = c(intercept, breakdown_summary)
    data_for_label = c("", data_for_label)
    labels = paste0(names(breakdown_summary)," = ", data_for_label)
    labels[1] = 'intercept'
  }



  if (!is.null(getinfo(DMatrix,"label"))){
    cat("\nActual: ", getinfo(slice(DMatrix,as.integer(idx)),"label"))
  }
  cat("\nPrediction: ", pred)
  cat("\nWeight: ", weight)
  cat("\nBreakdown")
  cat('\n')
  print(breakdown_summary)

  if (type == 'regression'){

    waterfalls::waterfall(values = breakdown_summary,
                          rect_text_labels = round(breakdown_summary, 2),
                          labels = labels,
                          total_rect_text = round(weight, 2),
                          calc_total = TRUE,
                          total_axis_text = "Prediction") +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
  }else{

    inverse_logit_trans <- scales::trans_new("inverse logit",
                                             transform = plogis,
                                             inverse = qlogis)

    inverse_logit_labels = function(x){return (1/(1+exp(-x)))}
    logit = function(x){return(log(x/(1-x)))}

    ybreaks<-logit(seq(2,98,2)/100)

    waterfalls::waterfall(values = breakdown_summary,
                          rect_text_labels = round(breakdown_summary, 2),
                          labels = labels,
                          total_rect_text = round(weight, 2),
                          calc_total = TRUE,
                          total_axis_text = "Prediction",
                          #fill_colours = c("blue", "red"),
                          #fill_by_sign = FALSE
    )  +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = inverse_logit_labels,
                         breaks = ybreaks, limits = limits) +
      scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
      #scale_fill_manual(values = c('darkblue', 'darkred')) +
      #scale_color_manual(values = c('darkblue', 'darkred')) +
      labs(title = "MyModelTitle",
           x = "MyVariables",
           y = "ModelProbabilities") +
      #coord_flip() +
      #theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
      theme(
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        #aspect.ratio = 1,
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
       strip.background = element_rect(fill = 'darkred'),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
      )

  }
}
```

I next run my newely modified function:

```
showWaterfall2(xgb.model,
               explained,
               xgb.test.data, test$data,  2, type = "binary")
```

I would like to make two minor adjustments to the function and `ggplot` code. The only part of the function I modified was the following (which corresponds to the `ggplot` part of the code):

```
waterfalls::waterfall(values = breakdown_summary,
                          rect_text_labels = round(breakdown_summary, 2),
                          labels = labels,
                          total_rect_text = round(weight, 2),
                          calc_total = TRUE,
                          total_axis_text = "Prediction",
                          #fill_colours = c("blue", "red"),
                          #fill_by_sign = FALSE
    )  +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = inverse_logit_labels,
                         breaks = ybreaks, limits = limits) +
      scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
      #scale_fill_manual(values = c('darkblue', 'darkred')) +
      #scale_color_manual(values = c('darkblue', 'darkred')) +
      labs(title = "MyModelTitle",
           x = "MyVariables",
           y = "ModelProbabilities") +
      #coord_flip() +
      #theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
      theme(
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        #aspect.ratio = 1,
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
       strip.background = element_rect(fill = 'darkred'),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
      )
```

If I uncomment `#fill_colours = c("blue", "red")` and `#fill_by_sign = FALSE` I can manually color the bars myself. However I like the `waterfall` package method of `fill_by_sign = TRUE` (negative signs get a different color to positive signs). However nowhere in the documentation of the `waterfalls` package ([here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/waterfalls/waterfalls.pdf)) does it say how to change the base colors.

How can I chnage `ggplot` or `waterfalls` base colors?
How can I also make the text (the numbers inside the bars) larger? Adding `text = element_text(size = 20)` to the `theme()` section doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the base colours for `fill_by_sign = TRUE` in the waterfall function by editing the waterfall.R file within the sub-folder of the waterfalls package (eg. waterfalls_0.1.2.tar.gz).

Change the two lines that follow the line

```
fill_colours <- ifelse(values >= 0,
```

to eg.

```
gg_color_hue(4)[6],
gg_color_hue(5)[6])
```

Then install the modified package in R and run your function again.

The first line indicates which colour should be given to positive changes in the waterfall chart. The second line, to negative changes.

The number within [ ] is the number of colours.

The number within ( ) is the colour no.

Change those values to get the colour combination that you want.

Preview your colours in [ ] with

```
gg_color_hue <- function(n) {
    hues = seq(15, 375, length = n + 1)
    hcl(h = hues, l = 65, c = 100)[1:n]
}

n <- 6
plot(1:n, pch = 16, col =cols, cex=5)
```